# What is the proper way of handling a mouse drag?

Tags: c++, windows

I need to implement mouse drag events which look something like this:

```
class MouseDragEvent
{
public:
   uint m_btn;
   uint m_x, m_y;
   uint m_delta_x, m_delta_y;
};
```

I think I will need to check for WM_LBUTTONDOWN and WM_LBUTTONUP messages and manually find the change in x and y. Is there a drag message or a better way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Start by detecting `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`. Record the starting coordinates where the mouse button was pressed. Check for `WM_MOUSEMOVE`, and when the mouse has moved outside the rectangle determined by [`GetSystemParameters(SM_CXDRAG)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724385(v=vs.85).aspx) and `GetSystemParameters(SM_CYDRAG)` use [`SetCapture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646262(v=vs.85).aspx) to capture the mouse. At this point continue responding to `WM_MOUSEMOVE` and check for `WM_LBUTTONUP`. You might want to change the mouse cursor at this point. Also check for [`WM_CAPTURECHANGED`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645605(v=vs.85).aspx), which means the drag has been aborted. After the drag is complete call [`ReleaseCapture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646261(v=vs.85).aspx).

**Edit:** Most of this process can be automated with the [`DragDetect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646256(v=vs.85).aspx) function. Call this function from the WM_LBUTTONDOWN handler.

Comment: Can't you call `SetCapture` in `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`?  Or does that break double-click recognition?  In fact, I think you should, otherwise dragging starting near (within `SM_CXDRAG` of) a border might not work.

Comment: @Ben Voigt, I think you're right. It's been a while since I had to do this, I was just working from memory.

Comment: WRT `DragDetect`, that sounds like a modal message loop.  Be very careful before using it.  (i.e. research the consequences)

Comment: One should keep in mind that even a regular release by the window itself triggers a WM_CAPTURECHANGED.

Answer (score 0):

There are drag-and-drop APIs in Windows (e.g. `RegisterDragDrop`), but concerned with the from- and to- windows (often in different applications), not the coordinates.

If you want to deal with delta-x and delta-y coordinated, then processing button down and button up messages is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/rdragdropfiles.aspx

This may also be helpful:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163915.aspx